# How to populate the vsdbg folder with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to set up debugging inside a docker container via vsCode.

Initially I was successful in doing this by adding the following line to my docker-compose file:

```
    volumes:
  - ~/.vsdbg:/remote_debugger:rw
```

Which mounted a local folder from my windows %UserProfile% folder.

[image]

I then tried to get another developer to do this on their machine, however their .vsdbg folder was empty,

My question is, what populates this folder? As I've not been able to reproduce filling the folder with the debug files

Comment: why does your screenshot show a file and not a folder? And why doesn't it have a dot at the start of its name like you specified? And what's up with the indentation of your YAML?

Comment: The screenshot is the contents of the folder